# Add customized attributes into cas server response

Tags: jwt, cas

I have configured my CAS server to send response as JWT, so when it communicated with CAS client application by service ticket, which now in form of a JWT (actually a JWS) ticket parameter.

There are some default attributes contained in this token about the authentication action and principal information, but we also want to add some customized attributes as keys and values into this token before we handle it to be used.

Is there any way to configure the CAS server and achieve this in a good manner?

Comment: Enhanced the question structure to make it more reader-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to specify the attributes you wish to release in the JWT in the authentication source, or you need to define separate attribute repositories and build up your own attributes there, and then release them. Attributes stuffed in the JWT need to first be created either by you or the authn/attribute source, and then they need to be allowed for release.